# What is WinForms "Autocomplete Append" called in a web context?

Tags: html, autocomplete, autofill

In native WinForms programming there was the concept of ["AutoComplete" with a mode "Append"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode) where, as you type, the rest of the textbox would fill in with a suggestion which would be highlighted.  If the user continued typing, that suggestion would naturally be replaced with the text entered, and the auto-complete suggestion would append again if available.

In web contexts, I have only seen auto-complete implemented as a selection dropdown below the input textbox (e.g. [jquery autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)).  There's also the input tag autocomplete attribute, but the options can't be controlled by javascript.  Searching for "autocomplete" and "autofill" dead-end with issues relating to the autocomplete attribute.

If "AutoComplete Append" is used in a web context, does it go by a different name?

Is there a reason that this paradigm is avoided (or, doesn't even exist) in web development?  (it seems particularly useful in mobile websites where screen real-estate is at a premium)